# What's the easiest way to copy postgreSQL tables from a schema to Snowflake?

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to copy tables from a postgreSQL schema to Snowflake (including data). What's the easiest way to do this?

My postgreSQL database lives in AWS RDS.

Comment: Are you referring to the DDL or the data or both?

Comment: Both the DDL and the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through this a couple of months ago and will share what I learned.

1. Snowflake does not recognize psql so a psql export/import will not work.
2. The recommendation I received from support was to export the tables as csv files, recreate the DDL, and then stage the csv files in S3.
3. There are third party tools that help connect and sync Postgres databases to Snowflake. [Stitch](https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/amazon-rds-postgresql/snowflake/) being the one my group looked at.

So you can write your own integration or use Stitch to connect the two. There could be a more effective way to do this but if you are moving a large database over, I am afraid there is not an easy way to do this. That said, it is not terribly difficult but will take time to move everything over. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I recently open sourced a small library to make it easy to sync Postgres tables to Snowflake. It uses `COPY` to extract data efficiently from Postgres (as CSV), and then `PUT` plus `COPY/MERGE` to load the data into Snowflake.

https://github.com/scottpersinger/pgwarehouse

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following community article which explains the steps to migrate.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/PostgreSQL-to-Snowflake-ETL-Steps-to-Migrate-Data

This is from one of the Snowflake partners who provides the tools to migrate the data.